# Extract part of a variable in batch

Tags: variables, batch-file, extract

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%g in (list.txt) do (
    set var=%%g
    set var=!var: =*!
    dir /b "!var!*.txt" > log.txt
    echo !var! > tempfile.txt
    for %%? in (tempfile.txt) do ( 
        set /A len=%%~z? - 2 
    )

    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%g in (log.txt) do (
        set var=%%g
        echo.!var!
        echo.!len!
        call set var=!var:~!len!,6!
        echo.!var!
        pause
    )   
)
```

The first for loop of this code reads in a line of text from "list.txt"  This file contains many lines that have a variable amount of characters like this:

```
 Check This File
 Check That Doc
```

For each line it then replaces the spaces with wild cards and searches against a directory and creates a temporary text file containing all file names starting with the line.  It also counts the length of the line.  Each file name in he directory would be something like this:

```
 Check.This.File.T01R45.foo.txt
 Check.This.File.T01R46.foo.txt
```

The last for loop reads the temporary text file line by line and attempts to remove all characters so that only the following exists:

```
 T01R45
 T01R45
```

I am attempting to use the following syntax for the set command:

```
 set var=%var:~num_chars_to_skip,num_chars_to_keep%

 num_chars_to_skip=variable set by counting characters from "list.txt"
```

My problem arises with line 16 of my code:

```
 set var=!var:~!len!,6!
```

The syntax expects a value not a variable for num_chars_to_skip and thus fails.  I am expecting to see with my second last statement to see the following:

```
 echo.!var! should show:     T01R45

 where it actually shows:    Check.This.File.T01R45.foo.txtlen
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a delayed expansion variable nested within another delayed expansion variable that way.  The cmd interpreter is trying to retrieve the value of a variable called `!var:~!`, then the literal string `len`, then a variable called `!,6!`.

To use `len` to pull a substring from `!var!` you'll have to call `len` in the percent style.  The ideal solution would be to use `!var:~%len%,6!`.  But since `len` is defined within the same parenthetical code block that gets a little tricky.

One solution is to move `call set var=!var:~!len!,6!` to a subroutine to massage and return `var`.  [See this function tutorial page](http://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php) for examples.

In this case, however, it might be easier simply to convert `!len!` to `%%n` notation with another `for` loop.

```
for %%N in (!len!) do set "var=!var:~%%N,6!"
```

Comment: Right on!  That totally worked.  I knew it was something with the delayed expansion variables but I am not skilled enough to understand them fully yet.